# What is this piece of hardware called?

Tags: furniture

It got bent and I need to replace it, there are 2 female parts one attached to sofa frame and one to sofa arm and the male part connects both. Thank you.

[image][image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQftw.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Might be an idea to let us know what generic search terms you've tried that haven't been successful, so people don't go ahead and repeat the same searches.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and show or tell us how this "connects". Is it a sliding mechanism?

Comment: Can you ask the sofa manufacturer? It looks like a custom part that you probably can't pick up at a hardware store.

Answer (score 2):

These are known as furniture connectors. Search for "furniture connector slider" and you might find a suitable design for yours. But I believe you might me able to straighten your part by hammer